# Is there any way to use Editor and Display templates with Dictionary<K,V> in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dictionary, mvc-editor-templates, display-templates

I usually make use of the **Editor** and **Display** templates when my model (or submodels) are `List<T>` objects. This way I avoid to "spoil" my code with several **foreach** constructs.

I wanted to know whether there is any way to use **Editor** and **Display** templates when the model is a `Dictionary<K,V>` object instead.

Thanks

Francesco

PS: answers with **Razor** are more appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editor/Display templates don't work well with `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Personally I avoid using this type as such especially with EditorTemplates as producing [correct field names](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) for the model binder could be a PITA.

I would recommend you defining a custom view model:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and then have a `IEnumerable<Item>` property on your view model for which you define Editor/Display templates. It will make your life much easier. Then all that's left would be to map between your model property (which potentially could be a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`) to the view model property.